How HA works when both Fencing agent VM and VM1(part of cluster) dies?
Say I have 3 servers-
Server 1 -> Fencing agent VM and VM1(part of pacemaker cluster)
Server 2 -> VM2 (part of pacemaker cluster)
Server 3-> VM3(part of Pacemaker cluster)
Say server 1 die due to power failure. What will happen? Will HA work?
